# Android : Asset file with same name on library (aar) and application notworking (lib asset file override by application asset file)

Tags: android

I have created one library, added a property file (app.property) in the assets folder.

Also, the application contains a property file (app.property) with the same name in the assets folder.

Due to the same name property file getting overrides with the application file.

How we can carry files with the same name in the asset folder at the library and application?